# Does anyone know about the photo on Lis's wall?

Tags: sword-art-online

In episode 7 of *Sword Art Online*, we get to see Lisbeth's smithy. On the announcement board, there is a pinned photo of her with three other people, but in that photo, she is a little kid.

Does anyone know how this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's supposed to be her old crew where she worked as a blacksmith. However, as the series went on, a lot of people died, so I suppose those 4 or 5 people were the ones who died.

Comment: Yea i can understand that... Maybe i didnt ask correctly... I wanted to know how can she be a little girl in that photo. Only 2 years have passed since they were transfered into the game

Answer (score 0):

I would guess something along the lines of a background program that can guess aproximately what you looked like in the past based on your current age, developmental growth, physical attributes, etc. Not that difficult of a program considering the technological power of SAO.